# Create class instance from string in dartlang

Tags: dart

I have created this class

```
class Opacity {
  String a,b,c;

  Opacity({this.a, this.b,this.c});
}
```

And I'm trying to dynamically create an instance of this class only using strings and an hashmap for arguments.

```
String type = "Opacity";
List<String> args = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b','c': 'c'}
```

And I have one constraint, I can't modify the `Opacity` class.

For creating the instance I thought about using reflection to dynamically create the class from string but I can't figure out how to pass the arguments dynamically.

Comment: You could do that using reflection, but that's only available for server/command-line apps, but not for Web, or Flutter. For such Web and Flutter apps it's probably better to create a factory constructor/method that knows how to deal with such strings and to create instances and pass parameters for a predefined set of classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For passing arguments dynamically to the constructor you can use `newInstance` method of `ClassMirror`.

For example

```
  MirrorSystem mirrors = currentMirrorSystem();
  ClassMirror classMirror = mirrors.findLibrary(Symbol.empty).declarations[new Symbol('Opacity')];
  print(classMirror);
  var arguments = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}.map((key, value) {
    return MapEntry(Symbol(key), value);
  });
  var op = classMirror.newInstance(Symbol.empty, [], arguments);
  Opacity opacity = op.reflectee;
  print("opacity.a: ${opacity.a}");
  print("opacity.b: ${opacity.b}");
  print("opacity.c: ${opacity.c}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Going from a string to a source name, and further to the thing denoted by that source name, is reflection. It's only available through the `dart:mirrors` library, or if you generate code ahead-of-time, perhaps using `package:reflectable`.

This is a point where Dart differs from a language like JavaScript, where you can inspect all values at run-time.

Without reflection, the only way you can call a constructor is if you have actual code performing that call in your code. That would mean that you have to have code like `Opacity(a: ..., b: ..., c: ...)` at least in one place in your code.
You could define a function like:

```
Opacity createOpacity(Map<String, String> args) => 
    Opacity(a: args["a"], b: args["b"], c: args["c"]);
```

Then you could perhaps register it by name as:

```
Map<String, Function> factories = {"Opacity": createOpacity};
```

and finally use it as:

```
var type = "Opacity";
var args = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'};
Opacity myOpacity = factories[type](args);
```